# Variable product id using wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I pass variable id with short code

```
[product_page id="99"]

do_shortcode('[product_page id='.$packages[0].']');
```

Tried the above method but its not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

```
function getproduct_page_fnc( $atts ) {
       $product_id = $atts['id'];
       
}
add_shortcode( 'product_page ', 'getproduct_page_fnc' );
```

call the function like

```
do_shortcode('[product_page id='.$packages[0].']');
```

make sure you get value in `$packages[0]`